# Using De-moivres to solve the following problem:

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, intuition

[image]

Part (i) I can solve and understand that the solutions are $Z=e^\frac{2ki\pi}{5}$ for                       $k = 0,1,2,3,4$

Its the part (ii) I cannot understand. Could someone kindly give me a detailed simple step by step explanation of your logic if you are able to solve it.

I can see how the quartic is obtained from expanding $(Z+1)^5 = Z^5 +10Z^3 +10Z^2 + 5Z +1$ And since this is equal to $Z^5$ the $Z^5$'s cancel and you are left with the quartic that they gave you, but where do i go from here?

With kind regards,

Thank you.

Comment: 1) Do you see how the quartic polynomial is related to the equation they pose? 2) Can you place that fifth-order equation into a form that looks like the you _could_ solve?

Comment: The quartic is equivalent to $\left(\frac{z+1}{z}\right)^5=1$.

Comment: Semiclassical I can see how the quartic is obtained from expanding $(Z+1)^5 = Z^5 +10Z^3 +10Z^2 + 5Z +1$ And since this is equal to $Z^5$ the $Z^5$'s cancel and you are left with the quartic that they give you, but where do i go from here?

Comment: André Nicolas Ok thanks for your answer i did actually realize that, but where do i go from here? In the question i asked for a step by step solution not hints.

Comment: We don't care what you asked for --- we are giving you hints because we know what is good for you. Now: can you see how the equation in Andre's comment relates to part (i), the part you were able to solve?

Comment: Sorry for my impatience Gerry, Is the solution $(\frac{Z+1}{Z})^5=1$ equal to the roots of part (i)? If so i'm still not sure how to proceed.

Comment: If you want to be sure I see a comment, you have to write @Gerry. Anyway, I'm sorry to see that S.B. has deprived you of the joy of figuring it out on your own.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Yes i do agree with your point about giving hints to enable an OP to figure it out for themselves as you said 'its what is good for you', because you gain more understanding. However, i must tell you that I am only a self taught mathematician (i don't have a degree in the subject) all I know is what i have read in books. Put simply i'm just someone who likes maths. So if some of my questions/comments come across as a little trivial/simple please bear this in mind ok?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As André Nicolas wrote in his comments, using the $\theta$ values you already discovered:
$(z+1)^5=z^5\Rightarrow(\frac{z}{z+1})^5=1\Rightarrow \frac {z}{z+1}=e^{i\theta}\Rightarrow z=e^{i\theta}(z+1)\Rightarrow e^{i\theta}=z(1-e^{i\theta})\Rightarrow z=\frac{1}{1-e^{i\theta}}$

Comment: thanks just what i needed to see.